# A good binary file format that allows meshes, skeleton bones and animations

Tags: file, animation, 3d, format, 3ds

I have a question. Is there any good file format (binary better) that allows meshes, skeletons and animations? .3ds doesn't export animations, and .iqm doesn't work very well. 
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Fbx supports animations, but it is close source.

Now I use pmx, a file format developed by anime amateurs. So it is so miniority. However you can find fully format description here [PMX (Polygon Model eXtended) 2.0](https://gist.github.com/lordscales91/47ae1b7577e52a2babee)
And vmd for animations [vmd file format](http://mikumikudance.wikia.com/wiki/VMD_file_format)

If you want to use some libraries or software,I recommend fbx. If you want to write your own, you can study about pmx, that is very simple and clear.

Comment: I decided to create my own Blender exporter, but thanks anyways.